# Images stop loading in Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fresco

I have an issue in my react-native@0.38 app, it only happens in android devices while in ios it works perfect.

I have a main feed view where I render multiple images (like instagram/fb does) all the images come from Amazon (S3) each image has (max)200kb. On the other hand, in every image I render a number which indicates the number of times the function OnLoad() from  is called.

So, the first time I open the app the images are shown as expected (every image shows load=1) but if I request new images (after 2-3 new requests) the new images don't show up anymore and it shows a blank container and load=0 instead. What I have noticed, at least in the simulator, is that if I go to another app from the device and I come back to my app, the load number increases by +1 in some of the images and they are re-rendered, some others keep showing the last load value and the image is somehow lost (white container) BUT some of the new images are loaded showing now load=1 ...

I thought that it might be a cache issue since it never goes up from 23MB but I tried clearing cache using react-native-http-cache and nothing changed...

could it be something related with fresco?

UPDATE:

So I "solved" the issue. Every request I was doing contained 15 pictures with ~200KB per picture, so now I implemented in my API a resize "on the fly" and the pictures from 900x900px are 350x350px and the size is about 80% smaller, this seems to work because the memory seems to handle this numbers in a better way and I can even download more data than before and the pictures are rendered in the list as expected...

Comment: Do you have a list? Does the list do view recycling?

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with the same problem, also React Native v0.38. It appears there is a serious bug with using lots of images for Android in React Native.

Listed as known bug on RN site: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/known-issues.html

More details here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8677